# Textfield's default vertical scrollbar covers the textfield's content in platform windows

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollbar, textfield

Textfield's default vertical scrollbar covers the textfield's content in platform windows

I have a textfield that looks like this and its scroll bar overlaps a few characters of the textfield's content

```
Container(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 42),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: isDisable == true
                        ? Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent)
                        : Border.all(
                            width: 1,
                            color: isError && controller.text.trim().isNotEmpty
                                ? red
                                : colorA2A7B5.withAlpha((255 * 0.5).toInt()),
                          ),
                    color:
                        isDisable == true ? colorA2A7B5.withOpacity(0.3) : null,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    minLines: 1,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(maxlength)
                    ],
                    enabled: !isDisable,
                    scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    maxLines: 3,
                    scrollController: _scrollController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 9.5, bottom: 9.5, right: 16, left: 16),
                    ),
                    style: Styles.baseNotoSansJPRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                )
```

I want to somehow hide the default scrollbar of the textfield or be able to customize it so that it doesn't overlap the textfield's content.

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomScrollBehavior for hidden scrollbar of textfield

```
class CustomScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  const CustomScrollBehavior();
  @override
  Widget buildScrollbar(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    // TODO: implement buildScrollbar
    return child;
  }
}
```

And use

```
ScrollConfiguration(
                  behavior: const CustomScrollBehavior(),
                  child: TextField(),
)
```